# Extract characteristics of project

Tags: git, command-line, github

I clone a Project from Github and i want to extract some features. Can someone give me an instructions to extract:

- Number of users work on this project?
- To extract the most change file? (has more commit)
- Number of commit on this file?
- Number of insertion/deletion on this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for users and their commit

```
git shortlog -s -n
```

to count the number of users

```
git shortlog -s -n | wc -l
```

for the number of commit to a certain file you can do

```
git log "path_to_file" | wc -l
```

and add 1 to the output divide it by 6 since there are 6 lines for every commit. my shell skills arent that good to do that pipeline

you can also do

```
git log --pretty=oneline "path_to_file" | wc -l
```

for insertion and deletions

```
git log --stat
```

gives information per commit, i guess you need to go over that and start counting

also, github can display the same information pretty nicely via stats and file diff stat

for file with most commits you need to go over each file and see the number of commits and take the largest

this is the batch file i've wrote. It could be better, but it should get you started

```
   for /r "Folder_Path" %%X in (*.*) do (
        (echo %%X  >> commits.txt
         git log --pretty=oneline %%X | wc -l >> commits.txt) 
        )
```

it will make a file with the filename and number of commits next to it. just take the largest